# PostgreSQL: Count number of columns in a row that contain a value

Tags: postgresql

Let's say I have a table with the following columns:

Id

Col1

Col2

Col3

Col4

.
.

*Note that I have 50 of these columns ('col1'...'col50')

For each row, I want to count the number of columns that start with 'col' (so col1, col2, etc.), that also contain a specific integer value (0, for example).

So if my data was:

```
Id, Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4
0, 0, 1, 2, 1
1, 1, 2, 0, 1
2, 1, 0, 5, 0
3, 0, 0, 0, 4
```

My result would be:

```
Id, Count
0, 1
2, 1
2, 2
3, 3
```

Obviously this needs to scale to the 50 columns, so I don't want to hard code the column names (I need to have it dynamic/looping).  I will also be repeating this with other values I am looking for, the meat of the issue can be simplified to the above result.

I wasn't sure how to accomplish this.  I thought about a function that takes in a column name, a lookup value and a counter, then returns a total and current counter position or something.  I would have to do a WHILE loop to call the function until the end counter is reached.

The goal is to replace something that works, but is an eye sore and not re-usable (with 50 columns):

Case col1 when 0 then 1 else 0 end + case col col1 when 0 then 1 else 0 end...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with t(id, col1, col2, col3, col4) as (values
  (0,0,1,2,1),
  (3,0,0,0,4))
select * from t cross join lateral (
  select count(*) as cnt
  from json_each_text(to_json(t))
  where key like 'col%' and value = '0') as j;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=43c470b86eb7a2557ffb5a2b710791d1) by [lad2925](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5070879/lad2025) (c)

[More about JSON functions.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html)

Comment: I really like this approach :) **[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=43c470b86eb7a2557ffb5a2b710791d1)**

Answer (score 0):

You could use some sort of `PIVOT`:

```
SELECT Id, cnt
FROM tab
JOIN LATERAL ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt_0
               FROM (VALUES(col1),(col2),(col3),(col4)) s(c)
               WHERE s.c=0) AS sub ON true
ORDER BY id;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=2217d2e64d4deadb157999d5800f9000)**

Answer (score 0):

If you know the column names in advance, you could build an array, unnest and aggregate to get the count of zeros in the row.
Example:

```
WITH t (Id, Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4) AS (
VALUES
(0, 0, 1, 2, 1),
(1, 1, 2, 0, 1),
(2, 1, 0, 5, 0),
(3, 0, 0, 0, 4)
)
, unnested AS (
SELECT id, (UNNEST(ARRAY[Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4]) = 0)::INT is_zero
FROM t
)
SELECT id, SUM(is_zero) zeros
FROM unnested
GROUP BY 1
```

Otherwise, use json functions to reshape the table, filter on the column name (key) and value and aggregate.

```
WITH t (Id, Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4) AS (
VALUES
(0, 0, 1, 2, 1),
(1, 1, 2, 0, 1),
(2, 1, 0, 5, 0),
(3, 0, 0, 0, 4)
)
SELECT id, COUNT(*)
FROM t, JSON_EACH(ROW_TO_JSON(t)) kv
WHERE kv.key ~ 'col\d+' 
  AND (kv.value::TEXT)::INT = 0
GROUP BY 1
```